# Difference between geodesic vector field and pre-geodesic vector field

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vector-fields, geodesics

A curve $L$ is a geodesic iff the tangent vector field $v$ associated with any parametrization of $L$ obeys
$$\nabla_{v}v=\kappa v$$
where $κ$ is a scalar field along $L $.
A vector field $v$ obeying the above equation is called a pre-geodesic vector field. The scalar field κ is then
called the non-affinity coefficient of v. If κ = 0, v is naturally called a geodesic vector field.

 We often take the equation with $\kappa=0$ in general relativity. Can someone explain me why is that ?? I understand the mathematical difference but what is the **physical significance** or any special characteristic of the equation when $\kappa \neq 0$ ?

Comment: This paper could probably help to answer your question: [Quasi-geodesics in relativistic gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.05891) by Valerio Faraoni and Geneviève Vachon.